# Error of session even though I'm not using that one

Tags: php, session, pdo

I'm having a issue.. I have two login forms, and they are going to use the same pages but it will have different functions depending on which type of account you have.

Anyway..

You will understand very clearly by seeing this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) or $_SESSION['username'] == true) {
?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="content">

        <div class="user_logged">

        <h3>Welcome <h3 class="red"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></h3></h3>
        <a href="profile.php">Profile</a><br/>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/>
        <a href="collect.php">Collect/save new ads</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['biz_username']) or $_SESSION['biz_username'] == true){
include 'dbc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="content">

        <div class="user_logged">

            <h3>Welcome <h3 class="red"><?php echo $_SESSION['biz_username'];?></h3></h3>
            <a href="profile.php">Profile</a><br/>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/>
            <a href="collect.php">Create a new ad</a>

        </div>
        <div class="mid_con">
            <h3>New<h3 class="red">Ads</h3></h3>
        <?php
            $n_adsquery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, ad_offer, content, expiration_date FROM biz_ads ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 0,5");
            $n_adsquery->execute();
            while ($row = $n_adsquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                $name = $row[1];
                $ad_offer = $row[2];
                $content = $row[3];
                $expiration_date = $row[4];
            }

            echo $name;
            echo $ad_offer;
            echo $content;
            echo $expiration_date;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>


<?php
} else {
    header ('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

When logging in as a "normal" user there's no error or anything, it more or less work perfect.
But when logging in through the other login form, it says that the "$_SESSION['username'] is undefined, even if I'm not using it when logging in through this form.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When I try your code and setting the session username and (after destroying the session) setting the biz_username. It works fine for me.
Maybe the problem is in setting the session?
Or try removing the == true after $_SESSION['username']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess the problem in first line when you check if $_SESSION['username'] = true you called $_SESSION['username']  So error message say "$_SESSION['username'] is undefined "

why you used it , just use this to check if session is true .

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Always learning something new from here! Problem solved! =)